# double click to open file for the second time opens application again

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a problem when opening files with an application I created.

I implemented a mechanism and changed the registry file like described here: http://tech.eternj.net/2009/07/visual-c-note-open-a-file-in-your-own-program-when-double-clicking-the-file/

to open the file with my application. This is working well, however if i have my application running and double click a another file, another instance of my app is getting started. I want the running app to open the double clicked file instead, how can I achieve that?

thanks for you help in advance!

Comment: Search for "Single instance program C#"

Comment: Refer this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/19326/2530848